# Error when sending Curl request with PHP: Bad Request

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to scrape data from an address where the state publishes personnel announcements. However, no matter what I tried, I could not succeed. I examined get and post requests with Burp Suite. As far as I can find, the page address I need is: https://www.ilan.gov.tr/api/api/services/app/Ad/AdsByFilter

I inspected the page with Burp Suite. I think I added everything the page wants to the function I prepared for the curl connection.

Am I not sending the data in json form correctly? I tried as many ways as I could find but failed.

I've included the details below.
Thanks in advance for your help.

```php
function scustom_curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $data = [
               "keys" => [
                     "txv" => [
                        44 
                     ], 
                     "ats" => [
                           5 
                        ] 
                  ], 
               "skipCount" => 0, 
               "maxResultCount" => 12 
            ]; 
    $payload = json_encode(array($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Host: www.ilan.gov.tr';
    $headers[] = 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.3.951992202.1654450742; _gid=GA1.3.480689736.1654596075';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Length: 65';
    $headers[] = 'Sec-Ch-Ua: "-Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="102"';
    $headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
    $headers[] = 'X-Request-Origin: IGT-UI';
    $headers[] = 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0';
    $headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json';
    $headers[] = 'Accept: text/plain';
    $headers[] = 'Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT';
    $headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
    $headers[] = 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

[Burp Suite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxpSC.jpg)

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: Anyway, in your code $data is already an array. You don't need to enclose it inside another array when you're encoding it to JSON!

Comment: @Adyson I've never seen it because I've always looked for the error elsewhere. It was purely my ignorance. Thank you very much for your quick reply. I was dealing with this problem for 2 days. :)

I couldn't see how to add the php code either. Sorry for adding it as a picture. I fixed it right away.

Answer (score 0):

```
$payload = json_encode(array($data));
```

should be just

```
$payload = json_encode($data);
```

because `$data` is already an array. You don't need to enclose it inside another array when you're encoding it to JSON.